# How to center text inside DropdownMenuItem in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Currently, when I create a DropdownMenu it always shows the text to the start.
I want it to be centered and didn't find any resource that answers that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `Box` wraps content size, so for a single view inside, without additional modifiers, `contentAlignment` makes no difference. For @Francesc's answer to work, you need to apply `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` to the box:

```kotlin
DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, 
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(text = "text")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this without `Box` using `textAlign` parameter and you also need `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`:

```kotlin
DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
    Text(
        text = "text",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The drop down item takes a composable, you can use a `Box` and set the content alignment to center

```
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
    ) {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                selectedIndex = index
                expanded = false
            }) {
                val disabledText = if (s == disabledValue) {
                    " (Disabled)"
                } else {
                    ""
                }
                Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                    Text(text = s + disabledText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```